# Change column-indices referred to in a for-loop

Tags: r, loops, variables, indexing

I have a for-loop which uses information from multiple different columns. I'm referring to the columns by their column index. However, due to some unforeseen event I now have to add new variables to the dataframe which increases the index for each relevant variable by 3. Due to the size of the loop, it would be a tedious task to do it for every column individually. Is it possible to increase all indices at once?

So for instance:

```
for(i in 2:nrow(testtab4[53]))
{
  if(testtab4[i, 53]<testtab4[i,57] & testtab4[i,39]<=2 & testtab4[i,36]==1)

#should be 

for(i in 2:nrow(testtab4[56]))
{
  if(testtab4[i, 56]<testtab4[i,60] & testtab4[i,42]<=2 & testtab4[i,39]==1)
```

Or even better would be a way to refer to the variables by their name instead of their index. Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Any help is much appreciated:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to columns by name to avoid this kind of thing. For example:

```r
testtab4 <- data.frame(a = c(3, 6, 9, 12, 15),
                       b = 6:10, 
                       c = 0:4, 
                       d = rep(1, 5))

for(i in 1:nrow(testtab4))
{
  if(testtab4[["a"]][i] < testtab4[["b"]][i] & 
     testtab4[["c"]][i] <= 2 & testtab4[["d"]][i] == 1)
    cat("Row", i, "is TRUE\n")
}
#> Row 1 is TRUE
#> Row 2 is TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>